# Excel, can't create hyperlink within a cell without text

Tags: microsoft-excel, macbook

I have created SEVERAL hyperlinks in blank cells in this workbook i'm working on, and then all of a sudden now, when I try to create a hyperlink within a cell, it automatically puts the link name in the cell.  When I replace the text, the link still works, yet when I delete the text, the link goes away with it.  I don't know what I did or changed, but I am very frustrated.

Comment: Share both hyperlinks, working & not working with us, & let us try both, will help us to fix it.

Comment: What exact steps did you take, when it still was working, to enter a hyperlink in a blank cell, so that the cell remained blank?

Comment: I built SEVERAL pages with blank cells that the cell itself maitains the link and then when I type in some type of text, it remains linked.  I did so by simply right clicking on the empty cell and then choosing hyperlink and then clicking on the cell I want to link to.  The only thing I can think of that might have messed something up is while continuing to work on the file, I secured several of the pages and even, mistakenly, used the security for the whole file.  I have tried reversing that, but it still won’t allow me to make an empty cell with a link.

Comment: Sorry to say, but I can not reproduce your problem, thus also not find a solution. If you try with a completely new file, do you still have the problem or not? I tried to follow your instructions, guessing steps that you left out, but my Excel 2007 shows a dialog which you did not mention, so I had to stop there as I don't know how you proceeded. Maybe your Mac version is different. Playing around I found something that possibly could relate, but I can't base my answer on guesses. If you edit your question with exact detailed steps to reproduce in a new file I will look again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a `NULL` string as a "Friendly Name".  This is because the `NULL` string is "too short" for the mouse-over to work.

This is true even if you use a formula to create the hyperlink:

[image]

If you try to erase the Name by using:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com","")
```

the cell becomes "un-clickable" *(hyperlink functionality is gone)*

The best you can do is to use a single space:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com"," ")
```